# Symfony forms disabled option in select

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

i have problem with disabled select option which exist in relation table. How i can to do it?

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status", inversedBy="orderWork")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="order_status",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */

private $status;
```

and in form ->

```
->add('status', EntityType::class, ['label' => 'Užsakymo būsena',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control' ,'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px; width:250px; height:30px;'],
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Status',
        'query_builder' => function ($em) {
            return $em->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC');
            },
    'choice_label' => 'name'])
```

Comment: Are you looking to disable few of the options in select box?

Comment: i read about option in select box, but i don't undestand how configure form for my example. When selected status in manyToMany table order_status

Comment: From what I got, you don't want to list all the options from `AppBundle:Status` entity in the select box. you can add a `andWhere()` condition in the above query for that. If your requirement is otherwise, please make clear of that.